# I'm trying to create a Settings Model for my api in Django. Custom File uploading is what tricking me

Tags: django, file-upload, django-rest-framework

I have 3 fields in my model. below is the code.

**Model.py**

```
class Settings(models.Model):
    typeOptions = (
        ('txt', 'text'),
        ('img', 'image'),
        ('json', 'json'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=typeOptions, default='txt')
    value = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, editable=False, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='%(class)s_created')
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, editable=False, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='%(class)s_updated')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Settings'
        verbose_name = 'Setting'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

as you see I've 3 types for my type field i can save text and json directly in my database as my value is a text filed but i want a custom file handler so i can see if type of the post is image than i need to upload the file and save path to database.

I'll be using it just for API so i'm not practically concerned about Django admin. I hope someone will be able to help me.

I need to work this Django Rest framework so when i send a post request it manage the data.

Comment: trying to upload file without **`FileField`**?

Comment: It feels weird that you have 1 field to store 3 different kinds of data. Might be better to have 3 nullable fields with the correct types. Additionally you might have issues uploading files via an API

Comment: @Shan Khaliq apart from that, how do you plan to save a ***image file*** into a **`TextField`**?

Comment: @JPG Please check again i intend to save the path of file not image file in database.

Comment: Yes i'm trying to upload without FileFiled.

Comment: @ResleyRodrigues I don't believe uploading with api is a problem as if we have a FileFiled in model it'll handle the uploading itself api will just receive data and pass it to model. i believe that's how it's been handled.

Comment: I think **`FileField`** is pretty simple to handle the file and its path

Comment: @ShanKhaliq Why you are *not using* FileField?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178935/discussion-between-shan-khaliq-and-jpg).